# Byte/bit size of one string.xml line, dimen.xml line in XML android

Tags: android, xml

I'm curious on how much bit or byte does a line in XML (values, settings, strings, dimensions..et cetera) has in Android?

I could not find something yet in here or online, so please direct me to the link if it already exists or provide an answer to the question.

Example: Let's say I have

**1: dimens.xml file with the following:**

and I have another

[image]

**2: dimens.xml file with the following:

[image]

Does that make any difference as far as size? Will having more lines in my first dimens make my app "heavier" than the one with only fewer lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML-File is compiled so that the dimension is an Object. If the XML-value is not used, it would probably be removed by the compiler. If you have several XML-files for the same value the compiler would use the property valid for the current module/flavour/etc.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html for the confirmation (search for 'compile'). Furthermore the generated R-class is showing this.

Comment: Can you please provide any online documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The String limit size is 2,147,483,647 characters.
It does not matter the size of a line if the String has this limit.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to give you more insights on what I'm looking for as far as answer,